# How to map one-to-many relationship with JAXB and JPA

Tags: java, xml, jpa, jaxb

I am using Apache Camel to retrieve information from a webservice. The retrieved information are unmarshalled with JAXB and mapped to an entity class to persist the information into a relational database (in this case Oracle).

There is a relation between retrieved information. First there are all **persons** retrieved which are involved in a **project**. In a second request all projects are retrieved. Every project has an owner which refers to the id of a person.

To make things more clearly, here some example responses from the webservice.

**Persons:**

```
<response>
 <people>
  <person>
     <ixPerson>2</ixPerson>
     <sFullName>XXX</sFullName>
     ...
  </person>
  <person>
     <ixPerson>3</ixPerson>
     <sFullName>YYY</sFullName>
     ...
  </person>
 </people>
</response>
```

**Projects:**

```
<response>
 <projects>
  <project>
     <ixProject>33</ixProject>
     <sProject>My Project 1</sProject>
     <ixPersonOwner>2</ixPersonOwner>
     ...
  </project>
  <project>
     <ixProject>34</ixProject>
     <sProject>My Project 2</sProject>
     <ixPersonOwner>3</ixPersonOwner>
     ...
  </project>
 </projects>
</response>
```

The following entities (only excerpts are shown) are used to map the XML with JAXB and persist them to database:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Person.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Person p")
@XmlType(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  private long id;

  private String fullname;

  //bi-directional many-to-one association to Project
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
  private List<Project> projects;
  ...
  @XmlElement(name="ixPerson")
  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @XmlElement(name="sFullName")
  public void setFullname(String fullname) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
  }
}
```

**Entity for projects:**

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Project.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Project p")
@XmlType(name="project")
public class Project implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Person
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="OWNER")
    private Person person;

    @XmlElement(name="ixProject")
    public void setId(long id) {
       this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="sProject")
    public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="ixProjectOwner")
    public void setPerson(Person person) {
      this.person = person;
    }
}
```

All persons are unmarshalled correctly and can be persisted to database. But when I unmarshal projects, the unmarshalled data looks like:

```
<project>
   <ixProject>12</ixProject>
   <sProject>Project 3</sProject>
   <ixPersonOwner>
      <ixPerson>0</ixPerson>
   </ixPersonOwner>
</project>
```

The table to persist the projects takes only the id of the person as owner and ixPerson is always 0.

How can I get the right reference to class/entity Person, so that I could persist it with JPA?

Is this possible with mixing JAXB and JPA in one class or do I have to split it, to achive my goals?